# Prototype get all img tags in div named slideshow

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am new to prototype and scriptaculous and I am trying to get all of the  tags in my div with an id of slideshow. How can I put these in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique, that's a rule of HTML. You should use a class name of "slideshow", not an ID.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<img src="a.gif" class="slideshow">
```

Here's your array:

```
var myArray = $('myDiv').select('.slideshow').toArray()
```

Here you can loop though all the elements without an array:

```
$('myDiv').select('.slideshow').each(function(element) {
        alert(element.src)
    })
```